# Compilation Error - Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

When hosting the application on local IIS all forms work fine without causing any errors but while hosting the application on the server some forms are showing the 'Compilation Error'

**To remove these error made following updations to the server side.

1. Restart the application pool.
2. Enable 32-Bit Application = true on server side.

Still getting the error on the forms.**

Is there any other way to find out the server side compilation errors.

What is exactly the compiler error code 1.

Detailed Error is as follows:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code 1.
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.8009;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.8015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you have installed required windows features to run IIS on your hosting server.

You can do it by following

```
Control panel > 
   Program features > 
     Turn on Windows features on or off
```

Then on the pop up window, navigate to;

```
Internet Information Services > 
    Word Wide Web Services > 
       Application Dev Features >
          Tick all required features (I have ticked all but CGI)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your reply. All these features are ON. Local IIS did not give the error, all works fine. But on Hosting the site on server or web hosting panel gives me the error. To get rid of that problem is there any other way or any changes to made.

Comment: Still same problem exists. Is it network related error? What is the cause of this error?

Comment: How did you move compiled files from local machine to hosting server? Did you just copy the bin?

Comment: Hello @kaf, we upload the files from local machines to hosting server using Filezilla by login into server file manager. we upload all the bin files. Is any change needed while uploading or it is wrong way?

Comment: If you have changed any publish settings, copying bin folder can cause a problem. It has happened to me before. Copy your entire site and see if it works.